# What's the difference between a Vector Database and Full-Text Search?

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, information-retrieval, vector-database

I'm currently in the process of building an information search system for my personal documents, and I've been reading about both Vector Databases (in regards to stuff like LangChain), and full-text searches. My question is, what's the difference? Both seem to be similar in that they search information and provide a result to an asked question.

I've done some research on this topic, and have read through the documentation of stuff like Elasticlunr.js and VectorDB.

Answer (score 2):

Vector databases are actually where the the vectorized strings of the documents are saved in. For example, `langchain.vectorstores.Chroma`, `langchain.vectorstores.FAISS` stores the vector embeddings of the document in-memory i.e., in RAM, where `langchain.vectorstores.Pinecone`, `langchain.vectorstores.MongoDBAtlasVectorSearch` stores the vector embeddings in Pinecone (cloud-based storage) and MongoDB, respectively.

On the other hand, full-text search are method of searching the vector embeddings that are more similar to the query given by the user on the basis of some similarity metric such as `cosine`, `euclidean`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! So there's no difference, then, between me using a vector database to store stuff and using some sort of search algorithm on it, and me using elasticlunr.js to just search indexes of my documents?

Comment: Yes. That is what I believe so according to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The way vector databases and Full-text search work are fundamentally different. While vector databases emphasize semantic similarity, full-text search databases emphasize lexical search.

So, the way we use vector databases is to use an embedding model to convert a string into vectors, and during retrieval, look for strings with semantically similar i.e. have similar meanings via metrics like cosine similarity.

However, a full-text search looks for lexical / spelling similarity (check [BM25 metric](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-2-the-bm25-algorithm-and-its-variables)).  So phrases like "scoop" and "ice cream" can have high semantic similarity but low lexical similarity.

While this might make full-text search seem outdated, there are still use cases for it. One of the major drawbacks of vector similarity is the reliance on embedding models. There could be domain-specific keywords present in your phrase, which is not seen by embedding models much during training (especially if the technologies are more recent) and hence are not captured properly in the embedding vectors. In this case, full-text search outshines as it does word-to-word matches.

This drawback has led many vector databases to incorporate the Hybrid search functionality to combine the best of both worlds.